# Dword conversion to dec in little endian

Tags: assembly, decimal, endianness, dword

Dword x was saved to memory as a series of bytes 123, 29. How much is    the value of x in decimal system using little endian?

The answer to this question is `7547`.

Can somebody explain this to me step by step? I already know that little endian reverses the order, but this doesn't give this answer. I tried to do conversion to another system, but it still gives me the wrong answer.

Comment: 7547 (decimal) in little endian `DWORD` is 7B 1D 00 00, not only 7B 1D (123 29). In big endian it is 00 00 1D 7B. You see the different order of the same byte values.

Comment: A doubleword is 4 bytes on x86, not 2.  Unless you're on a hypothetical architecture where a "word" = 1 byte?  In the terminology of most non-x86 ISAs, a "word" is 32 bits and a dword is 64 bits, so this doesn't make sense for anything else either.  Maybe you meant "word" instead of "dword"?

Comment: There's no need to convert to hex and back. 123 + 29*256 = 7547

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to give you an alternative explanation to Kasper's answer:

In the decimal system you can "store" values from 0 to 9 in each digit. To store larger numbers, you use multiple digits. The value of a number written as "1234" is calculated like this:

1234 = 4 + 3*10 + 2*10*10 + 1*10*10*10

Using bytes you can store values from 0 to 255 in each digit. Just like in the decimal system, you can store larger values by using multiple bytes:

4, 3, 2, 1 = 4 + 3*256 + 2*256*256 + 1*256*256*256

123, 29 = 123 + 29*256 = 7547

("Little endian" means that the least byte is stored in memory first; just like you would read a decimal number from right to left.)

Answer (score 2):

As You're talking about DWORD and converting to little endian I'm assuming you have a 32 bits value big-endian encoding in input.

1. Let's convert [123 | 29 | 00 | 00] to HEX: **[7B | 1D | 00 | 00]** => decimal representation is **2065498112**
2. Let's invert: **[00 | 00 | 1D | 7B]** => decimal representation is **7547**

Comment: There's no mention of big endian or hex within the question.  Using them here just adds confusion.